# .NET - Instrumentation Library For Azure SDK

Tags: .net, azure, instrumentation

I'm working on instrument our services.

managed to add instrumentation libraries for:

- Incoming Http Request.
- Outgoing Http Requests.
- Grpc Requests/Responses.
- MongoDB
- AWS SDK.

As can be seen below:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddTracing(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(ActivitySourceProvider.ActivitySourceName)
                ? services
                : services.
                    AddSingleton<ActivitySourceProvider>().
                    AddOpenTelemetryTracing(
                        tracerProviderBuilder =>
                            tracerProviderBuilder.
                                SetResourceBuilder(
                                    ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(ActivitySourceProvider.ActivitySourceName)).
                                AddSource(ActivitySourceProvider.ActivitySourceName).
                                AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation().
                                AddMongoDBInstrumentation().
                                AddGrpcClientInstrumentation(grpcClientInstrumentationOptions => grpcClientInstrumentationOptions.SuppressDownstreamInstrumentation = true).
                                AddHttpClientInstrumentation().
                                AddAWSInstrumentation().
                                AddOtlpExporter(
                                    openTelemetryExporterOptions =>
                                    {
                                        var openTelemetryCollectorUrl =
                                            EnvironmentVariables.TryGet(InfrastructureContext.OpenTelemetryCollectorUrlEnvironmentVariableName);
                                        if (openTelemetryCollectorUrl is not null)
                                        {
                                            openTelemetryExporterOptions.Endpoint = new Uri(openTelemetryCollectorUrl);
                                        }
                                    }));
```

I wonder if there is library for instrumenting Azure SDK, some thing like the following line:

```
tracerProviderBuilder.AddAzureInstrumentation();
```

Does anyone know about library that achieves this?

Comment: There are a lot of azure sdks around, any specific service you want to instrument?

Answer (score 0):

We have OpenTelemetry support in Azure SDK for .Net as well, which is similar to Amazon Web Services.

Below are few ways where we can enable it:

1. We can add below variable in application settings and add true
   `AZURE_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLE_ACTIVITY_SOURCE`
2. Or we can add the variable in the functions as below and set it to true, this can be customized in respective code languages

   ```
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Azure.Experimental.EnableActivitySource", true);
   ```
3. Add below configurations to our project file:

> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>     <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="Azure.Experimental.EnableActivitySource" Value="true" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

These are the few things we need to follow to enable the activity source.

From MS Docs we can understand how to add the OpenTelemetry Instrumentation code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly ActivitySource MyActivitySource = new ActivitySource(
            "OTel.AzureMonitor.Demo");

    public static void Main()
    {
        using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSource("OTel.AzureMonitor.Demo")
            .AddAzureMonitorTraceExporter(o =>
            {
                o.ConnectionString = "<Your Connection String>";
            })
            .Build();

        using (var activity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("TestActivity"))
        {
            activity?.SetTag("CustomTag1", "Value1");
            activity?.SetTag("CustomTag2", "Value2");
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("Press Enter key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
```

Have a look on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=net) and a [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/introducing-experimental-opentelemetry-support-in-the-azure-sdk-for-net/) stating devblogs.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the example of adding instrumentation code just adding an azure monitor exporter (I believe that the exporter sends traces to some azure insight service), and the switch that you're doing activates some source that you did not listening to.
I'll try it ASAP, thanks.